# Model returns multiple values during inference, but expected is exactly one output value

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I have a tf model of given summary:

```
Model: "model"
Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
input_1 (InputLayer)        [(None, 1024, 9)]         0         
conv1d (Conv1D)             (None, 1024, 1024)        28672        
re_lu (ReLU)                (None, 1024, 1024)        0         
conv1d_1 (Conv1D)           (None, 1024, 64)          196672    
re_lu_1 (ReLU)              (None, 1024, 64)          0         
dense (Dense)               (None, 1024, 1024)        66560     
dense_1 (Dense)             (None, 1024, 1)           1025      
                                                                 
Total params: 292,929 Trainable params: 292,929 Non-trainable params: 0
```

I've preapred the `inputs` tensor and it looks like this:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 1024, 9), dtype=float64, numpy=
array([[[2.88565600e+04, 2.88415400e+04, 2.88415300e+04, ...,
         5.92000000e+02, 2.68717000e+00, 7.75434895e+04],
        [2.88415300e+04, 2.88391800e+04, 2.88364700e+04, ...,
         3.80000000e+02, 8.36111000e+00, 2.41110700e+05],
        [2.88391900e+04, 2.88597400e+04, 2.88391800e+04, ...,
         4.94000000e+02, 1.46990300e+01, 4.23977006e+05],
        ...,
        [2.96478600e+04, 2.96478600e+04, 2.96478600e+04, ...,
         2.24000000e+02, 3.16775000e+00, 9.39170402e+04],
        [2.96478700e+04, 2.96456900e+04, 2.96422200e+04, ...,
         4.22000000e+02, 3.72039000e+00, 1.10288124e+05],
        [2.96457000e+04, 2.96389700e+04, 2.96389700e+04, ...,
         2.69000000e+02, 1.79933000e+00, 5.33333054e+04]]])>
```

I expect only single number output, but when I try to use the model and feed it with the above input i get 1024 predictions instead of 1:

```
model.call( inputs, training=False, mask=None)

<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 1024, 1), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[[28849.605],
        [28859.383],
        [28880.047],
        ...,
        [29644.61 ],
        [29644.61 ],
        [29667.752]]], dtype=float32)>
```

Here, you can see that it returns 1024 predictions, but the model was trained to return exacly one number, expected is only one prediction from the provided input. How should I properly feed the input so that I get the proper working of the network and one prediction? Is there some problem with the dimensionality of the input?

Comment: I am not sure I follow, I try to feed the input '(None, 1024, 1)' with single feed to get one prediction. Could you explain what should I change exactly to feed it correctly?

Comment: can you provide a little more context? what are your inputs and expected output for your data? is this is a classification problem?

Comment: My input is an an array of shape 1024x9 scalars and expeted output is single scalar value, but it produces 1024 values, I assume that I am feeding it improperly, but I don't have a clue why and how to correct it.

Comment: Add a `GlobalMaxPooling` layer or `Flatten` layer after your last `Conv1D` layer and your problem is solved. Reason: a `Conv1D` layer returns a 3D output and you are expecting a 2D output at the end of your model. Note that `Dense` layers are always applied to the last dimension of a tensor by default.